# Redux Middleware currying

Tags: redux

I have this question in my head, not sure if this is validate or not, below it's an example of redux middle console log out the store.

```
const logger = store => next => action => {
  console.log('dispatching', action)
  let result = next(action)
  console.log('next state', store.getState())
  return result
}
```

I can see it's using **currying**, so in redux is calling as `logger(store)(store.dispatch)(action)` (Correct me if i am wrong). My question is why we currying here instead just

`(store, next, action) => { // do the rest }`

Thanks for any suggestion I am slowly moving into functional programming too to get my head up rhythm with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think redux wants to provide three hooks to developers.

We can split the call chain `logger(store)(next)(action)` into

```
let haveStoreAndDispatch = logger(store);
let haveNext = haveStoreAndDispatch(next);
let haveAction = haveNext(action);
```

Then we get three hook functions.
In `haveStoreAndDispatch` callback function, store have been created.
In `haveNext` callback function, we have get the next middleware.
In `HaveAction` callback function, we can do something with the previous middleware's result `action`.

Callbacks `haveStoreAndDispatch` and `haveNext` just be called only once in `applyMiddleware(...middlewares)(createStore)`.